# Is it possible to install a specific .sty (for texstudio) using apt?

Tags: latex

For some purpose I need to have `fontawesome.sty'. This .sty is a part of texlive-fonts-extra package which can be installed using apt. But I don't want to install whole texlive-fonts-extra package.

Is there a way to install 'fontawesome.sty' only and not whole of texlive-fonts-extra.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you are running Ubuntu, Debian or a Debian based distro.)

It is not possible to install `fontawesome.sty` only. You can however, download the `texlive-fonts-extra` package, extract the `fontawesome.sty` from it and install it manually. Here are the steps:

```
mkdir fontdownload
cd fontdownload

sudo apt-get download texlive-fonts-extra

dpkg -x texlive-fonts-extra_2019.202000218-1_all.deb ./

sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/
sudo cp -v ./usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesome.sty /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesome.sty

cd ..
rm -rf fontdownload
```